# Is there a way to highlight a specific item in the search results?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I have been trying to implement a slight change in the behavior of the chosen dropdown search results, but there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to get at them. I have a list of countries preceded by three-letter ISO country code. I would like to be able to search as usual, but highlight the country if there is an exact match on the country code. The problem is that the matching country code will not always be the first item in the list. A more general request would be able to access the result list, and set the selection to some item other than the first.

By inspection, it looks to me like the search results only exist as a jquery  object and within that the list items include a data-option-array-index with the original option list index, so I could find the item that I know I want highlighted in that DOM object and set the class "highlighted". But I also might need to scroll it into view, and messing with the underlying DOM directly is not ideal, so it would really be nice to have access to Chosen functions that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out, by accessing DOM. I have the index in the initial array that I want to highlight, and the following code will do it, assuming it is in the result list (using lodash _.find):

```
var highlightChosenResult = function(index) {
  var resultList = $('li.active-result');
  var result = _.find(resultList, function(el) {
    return +$(el).attr('data-option-array-index') === index;
  });
  if (result) {
    this.chosenApi.result_do_highlight($(result));
  }
}
```